# Are Remote commit hooks in subversion possible?

Tags: linux, svn, version-control, svn-hooks

my current setup is as follows:

- We have a Linux samba share that contains all the repository folders (with the hooks folder inside, amongst the others)
- All the developers have the share mapped as a network drive, and import to a local directory (normally C:\Server\RepositoryName) where they work on their files.
- All the machines accessing the drive (unfortunately) run windows.

What I'm aiming to do is to have a hook on the Linux server that detects when a commit has been made, by which project, the revision number, the name of the developer who committed, etc. I looked into the hooks files, but they seem to be ran by the client. Is there a way to monitor svn changes and collect the relevant information from the Linux server?

Comment: Being a purely technical question, this belongs to StackOverflow (please don't repost it there, it will be automigrated if enough people vote to close it here).

Comment: Thanks Péter, I thought the fact that this was a question based around a team of developers made it worthy of the programmers' channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the hooks are executed by svnserve. Check your hook scripts, svnserve configuration and http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#hook-debugging